# JavaScript - HTML string erring with unexpected EOF

Tags: javascript, html, string

I have an HTMl string that is stored in a database. When I go to set the value of a javascript variable with this string on the front-end via my templating engine (Leaf), it stores escaped as:

```
var string = &lt;p&gt;It&#39;s a round about way.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&lt;!-- pagebreak --&gt;But Maybe this is the way?&lt;/p&gt;;
```

I'm trying to set this value as the content value for TinyMCE, but JavaScript produces an Unexpected EOF error when reading this string and points to a & character, which I presume is the first character of the new line. I tried on the back-end to replace occurrences of string \r\n with a 
 so it would play nicer with JavaScript but the changes didn't seem to take. I tried encoding/decoding the string but that didn't help. Perhaps someone can help shed some light on this seemingly trivial task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you just need to put quotes around the string...

Comment: You've started your code block with `var string =`, suggesting it's JavaScript, but then it's followed by something that isn't a JavaScript string. It's hard to help you if we don't know what you're actually dealing with. If you're actually dealing with what you've shown, then it's a basic syntax error: You need to put quotes around the string.

Comment: I should have added additional context, like the raw HTML string had \r\n in it and javascript wasn't escaping those characters and in turn was creating a new line (and in turn creating the EOF error). I parsed it out at the API call and managed to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript was rendering \r\n characters found in the string instead of escaping them. Parsed it out in the server-side code instead of handling in JS.